# Why didn't humanity end?

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

When planting crops on Cletus's Farm, you have the option to plant Triffids.  The game says that you are rewarded with "End of Humanity".  I planted these to see what would happen, but when they were finished and harvested, nothing happened.

Do you have to be at a certain point in the story or have people on your friends list for something to happen, or is this just a joke that yields money and XP like the other plants?

[image: Triffids]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this forum post](http://tstotips.com/2013/03/05/repost-im-scared-about-what-will-happen-if-i-plant-triffids/).

Triffids are a reference to Triffids from [The Day of the Triffids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_of_the_Triffids) and more info can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triffids). It sounds like an end of the world kind of book.

But otherwise all they give are 1200 XP and no money. They do not end your game or reset anything.

Comment: When I planted them they were fine but then the next time I went to log in it reset my game and I had to start all over again

Comment: @Cass My town also was reset, but I think it was more an issue with EA.  I was able to log in several times after harvesting mine.